# jmeter html report generation - Skip a thred group

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have been searching for a way to exclude a thread group from the jmeter HTML report. All the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter) show how to include only a select thread group with names. However, I have several threadgroups and I need to get the report of ALL the thread groups EXCEPT one.

Example

```
jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter=^(Main)(-success|-failure)?$
```

This will include only the "Main" in the report. Is there a way to exclude "Main" from the report ?

Comment: Probably as with any other regex, `jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter=^(?!Main(?:-success|-failure)?$)(.*)`

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work.

Comment: I think this worked partially. When I run the script it generates "Main-1" , Main-2" etc due to the naming policy. How do I update this to "Main" and "Main-*" ?

Comment: Maybe `^(?!Main-?$)(.*)`? `^(?!Main)(.*)`?

Comment: I am testing https://regex101.com/r/mebFqS/1/  It picks up all except "Main". I need to pick up all except "Main" and "Main-*"

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think your second suggestion works.